# Qt creator process id changing

Tags: linux, bash

Qt is closed . But this process is still running with no CPU usage. Also the process id is continuously changing. Why is it running and changing pids by 2 ?
Also I noticed that if I run the ps command after some time the process id shifts by a multiple of 2.

ps aux | grep qt
1000      9883  0.0  0.0   8104   936 pts/0    S+   11:02   0:00 grep --color=auto qt

ps aux | grep qt
1000      9885  0.0  0.0   8104   940 pts/0    S+   11:02   0:00 grep --color=auto qt

ps aux | grep qt
1000      9888  0.0  0.0   8104   940 pts/0    S+   11:02   0:00 grep --color=auto qt

ps aux | grep qt
1000      9912  0.0  0.0   8104   940 pts/0    S+   11:03   0:00 grep --color=auto qt

Also how do I kill such a process ?

Thanks :)

Comment: you get process id +2 because you launch 2 processes: `ps` and `grep`
Also, I fail to understand why this is downvoted. Clearly, the op spent at least some time trying to understand what is happening and provided sufficient logs to solve the problem/question. I believe I am not the second person on earth who got confused by `ps` reporting `grep`'s pid like this at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing your `grep` entry, Qt Creator isn't even running.  You get the same result typing in something that you know doesn't even exist:

```
[root@111 camm]# ps aux | grep Hello
root      3106  0.0  0.0   4024   708 pts/0    S+   07:52   0:00 grep Hello
[root@111 camm]# ps aux | grep Hello
root      3108  0.0  0.0   4024   712 pts/0    S+   07:52   0:00 grep Hello
[root@111 camm]# ps aux | grep Hello
root      3113  0.0  0.0   4024   712 pts/0    S+   07:52   0:00 grep Hello
[root@11 camm]# ps aux | grep Hello
root      3117  0.0  0.0   4024   708 pts/0    S+   07:52   0:00 grep Hello
```

Comment: When I do ps , ps will show that in the list. But when I do ps | grep hello even though ps is the process , grep is the process shown. Is it that pipes work that way ?   How is the pipe read fd closed automatically ?